# Does the option "separator" still exist?

Tags: context

I am reading the book **ConTeXt Mark IV, an excursion**. It seems that the option named "separator" related to `\setupheads` is no longer available.

```
\setupheads
  [alternative=inmargin,
    separator=--]
\starttext
\chapter[lansing]{The Lansing family}
\section{The early years}
\stoptext
```

[image: The "separator" option related to \setupheads]

According to the manual, the **separator** option in the above code snippet would have the effect of replacing the dot with a hyphen (c.f. [page 13](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/ma-cb-en.pdf)). This option does not appear in the manual **ConTeXt commands** (c.f. [page 214](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/qrcs/setup-en.pdf#[0,%7B%22name%22:%22Fit%22%7D])).

**Note:** I am using **ConTeXt LMTX**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define a separator set with `\defineseparatorset`:

```
\defineseparatorset[dash][][--]

\setuphead
  [alternative=inmargin,
   sectionseparatorset=dash]

\starttext
\chapter[lansing]{The Lansing family}
\section{The early years}
\stoptext
```

[image]